# OpenCv and vectors to convert picture to YUV and then reverse it back

Tags: c++, image, opencv, vector

I have a problem using openCV, I need to split picture into vector to YUV color scheme and then reverse it back, I'm new in this stuff and i don't know how to solve my problem and also I couldn't find any solution. The problem is that after changing it from YUV back into basic, the basic picture is different from the one i had at the beginning of the process(and they should look the same), it looks like maybe color component is missing or something. Can anyone help me solve my problem?

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    //reading picture from pc and importing it into Mat variable
    Mat zdjecie, zdjeciePoZmianie, zdjecieOdwr, pom, zdjMerge;

    //zdjecie variable - have basic picture in it
    //zdjeciePoZmianie - new picture after converting to YUV and spliting it
    //zdjecieOdwr - to inverse the process to have basic picture from YUV pic
    //zdjMerge - variable when i merged vector into

    zdjecie=imread("/home/major/Downloads/Dan.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    imshow("pic before operations",zdjecie);

    //Separating picture components
    vector<Mat> vec1, vec2;
    cvtColor(zdjecie, zdjeciePoZmianie, CV_BGR2YUV);
    split(zdjeciePoZmianie,vec1);

    pom=Mat::zeros(Size(zdjeciePoZmianie.cols, zdjeciePoZmianie.rows),CV_8UC1);
    vec2.push_back(vec1[0]);
    vec2.push_back(vec1[1]);
    vec2.push_back(vec1[2]);

    merge(vec2,zdjMerge);

    imshow("after changing to YUV", zdjMerge);

    //Reversing to the basic pic
    cvtColor(zdjeciePoZmianie, zdjecieOdwr, CV_BGR2YUV);
    imshow("Reversed back", zdjecieOdwr);
    return a.exec();
}
```

This is how it looks YUV to normal

[image]

Comment: the problem has nothing to do with Qt.

Comment: Sorry then for including bad tag and thx for editting it out

Comment: You're performing the same `CV_BGR2YUV` conversion both times. If you want to convert *back* to BGR, you need to use `CV_YUV2BGR`.

Comment: @beaker ok X.x i feel stupid now that i didn't found out this by myself, but I was also side tracked by the guy that told me to do this cuz he said that i need to use same function two times. Anyway big thanks to You :)

Comment: @MatMaj Don't worry about it, we've all been there :)